# Excel 2007 - VBA Cut paste value from one cell to another below each other

Tags: excel, vba, cell

**I am counting strings like if a word is appearing 10 times. then that word is in cell a1 and count is in cell a2 ** - I am generating this from code...(SUM((LEN(range_chk)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(UPPER(range_chk),UPPER(Sheet2!E8),"")))/LEN(Sheet2!E8))
)  ( My data is in sheet1 and I am finding words in sheet2 ....FYI - range_chk is a offset function used in excel through name manager---and this code works fine)

I have tried `worksheet_change(byval target as range)` function but its going in `loop`.
please help on code.

What I need is

I am finding word : in cell A1:  Me

I am getting count : in Cell A2: 5

cutting from above cells n pasting it in

Cell A7 --"Me"   Cell B7---"5"

Next searched word: "Really" with count 3

cut n Paste in Cell A8 --"Really"  Cell B8-- 3

Next Searched word: "sense" with count 6

cut n Paste in Cell A9 --"sense"   cell B9 --6 ....and so on.

Then sort the range from A7:B9 according to count in ascending order.

Comment: If you have already tried some code, post it here and maybe someone can see where you are going wrong. As a pointer, if you are using the worksheet_change event to change a value in your worksheet you may want to look up EnableEvents...

Comment: I've read over this question a few times now and I still can't figure out what the heck is being asked. You don't mention in your question how you come up with this count or even **where** you generate it from, a database? a different worksheet? another workbook? a word document? Without this sort of information it's impossible for anyone here to work out the specific intent of the question, never mind provide an answer.

Comment: I don't know what is being asked either, I answered this question with code that will fix something that you have tried yourself. That's as far as we can help you.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the Worksheet_Change method do this and it will stop looping:
It's looping because another thing on the worksheet changes when you run your code.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    'Your code here

    Application.EnableEvents = True
end sub
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try this n see if it works. Kindly guide on offset function. target.offset function because my next searched word, will come below each one. suppose, 1) "Me" with count 5 ...2) "Really" with count 3 ...3)"to" with count 6.....and so on...will come below each other.